# Why this table does not appear centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,enumitem,ragged2e}

\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{%
  \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{%
  leftmargin = *               ,
  label      = \textbullet     ,
  nosep                        ,
  before     = \tablistcommand ,
  after      = \tablistcommand
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
  \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2in}}@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{BSL} & \textbf{Agents} & \textbf{Practices}
    & \textbf{Primary barriers} & \textbf{Secondary barriers} \\
    \midrule
    1 & Not known to consistently cause diseases in healthy adults
      & standard microbiological practices
      & \begin{tabitemize}
        \item no primary barriers required,
        \item  PPE
        \end{tabitemize}
      & bench and sink required \tabularnewline
    2 & \begin{tabitemize}
        \item Agents associated with human diseases
        \item Routes of transmission include per-cutaneous injury,
          ingestion, mucous membrane exposure
        \end{tabitemize}
      & BSL-1 practice plus:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item limited access
        \item Biohazard warning signs
        \item ``Sharps'' precautions
        \item Biosafety manual defining any needed waste
          decontamination or medical surveillance polices
        \end{tabitemize}
      & Primary barriers:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item BSCs or other physical containment devices used for all
          manipulations of agents that cause splashes or aerosols of
          infectious materials
        \item PPE: Laboratory coats, gloves, face and eye protection,
          as needed
        \end{tabitemize}
      & BSL-1 plus:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item Autoclave available
        \end{tabitemize}\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear centered because it is too wide for the page and overflows the right margin. Try setting different page dimensions e.g. using the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. Also, you can visualise the margins e.g. by the `showframe` option. To achieve both add

```
\usepackage[showframe,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
```

to the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `tabularx` with width `\linewidth` and column types `>{\RaggedRight}X}`. With this your table will fit text width. To see page layout, you can help yourself with `\uasepackage{showframe}` or design layout with `geometry` package, for example `\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}`.

With this measures you will obtain something like this:

[image]

Beginning part of your code considering aforementioned is:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{%
  \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{%
  leftmargin = *               ,
  label      = \textbullet     ,
  nosep                        ,
  before     = \tablistcommand ,
  after      = \tablistcommand
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
  \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{4}{>{\RaggedRight}X}@{}}
...
```